# Numpy - How to replace elements based on condition (or matching a pattern)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, say:

```
>>> a=np.array([[0,1,2],[4,3,6],[9,5,7],[8,9,8]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [4, 3, 6],
   [9, 5, 7],
   [8, 9, 8]])
```

I want to replace the second and third column elements with the minimum of them (row by row), except if one of these 2 elements is < 3.
The resulting array should be:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],# nothing changes since 1 and 2 are <3
   [4, 3, 3], #min(3,6)=3 => 6 changed to 3
   [9, 5, 5], #min(5,7)=5 => 7 changed to 5
   [8, 8, 8]]) #min(9,8)=8 => 9 changed to 8
```

I know I can use clip, for instance `a[:,1:3].clip(2,6,a[:,1:3])`, but

1) clip will be applied to all elements, including those <3.

2) I don't know how to set the min and max values of clip to the minimum values of the 2 related elements of each row.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the >= operator to first select what you are interested of:

```
b = a[:, 1:3]  # select the columns
matching = numpy.all(b >= 3, axis=1)  # find rows with all elements matching
b = b[matching, :]  # select rows
```

Now you can replace the content with the minimum by e.g.:

```
# find row minimum and convert to a column vector
b[:, :] = b.min(1, keepdims=True)
```

Comment: Your `matching` array is better defined as `matching = np.all(b >= 3, axis=1)`. And your assignment would probably be clearer if you did something like `b[:, :] = b.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)`, or if your version of numpy does not support `keepdims=`, something like `b[:, :] = b.min(1)[:, np.newaxis]` instead of the transpose trick. Other than these nitpicks, this is the way I would do it too, +1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I agree, they do make this better. Edited to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: @Dominique this SO user deserves a tick... \*sighs at newbs\*

Answer (score 1):

We first defined a `row_mask`, depicting the `<3` condition, and then apply a `min`imum along an axis to find the minimum (for rows in `row_mask`).

The `newaxis` part is required for the broadcasting of a 1dim array (of `min`imums) to the 2-dim target of the assignment.

```
a=np.array([[0,1,2],[4,3,6],[9,5,7],[8,9,8]])
row_mask = (a[:,0]>=3)
a[row_mask, 1:] = a[row_mask, 1:].min(axis=1)[...,np.newaxis]
a
=> 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [9, 5, 5],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:

```
a[np.where(np.sum(a,axis=1)>3),1:3]=np.min(a[np.where(np.sum(a,axis=1)>3),1:3],axis=2).reshape(1,3,1)
```

Here's a breakdown:

```
>>> b = np.where(np.sum(a,axis=1)>3) # finds rows where, in a, row sums are > 3
(array([1, 2, 3]),)
>>> c = a[b,1:3] # the part of a that needs to change
array([[[3, 3],
        [5, 5],
        [8, 8]]])
>>> d = np.min(c,axis=2) # the minimum values in each row (cols 1 and 2)
array([[3, 5, 8]])
>>> e = d.reshape(1,3,1) # adjust shape for broadcast to a
array([[[3],
        [5],
        [8]]])

>>> a[np.where(np.sum(a,axis=1)>3),1:3] = e # set the values in a
>>> a

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [9, 5, 5],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```